# SequenceFile partition in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I want to understand how Spark partition so I did as following:

```
JavaPairRDD<Text, CustomObj> bigRDD = ctx.sequenceFile("path to sequenceFile", Text.class, CustomObj.class);
        System.out.println(bigRDD.partitions().size());
```

Suppose "path to sequenceFile" contains 8 different sequence files and it has total 21 MB. The output give 8 as number of partitions.

```
JavaPairRDD<String, String> bigRDD1 = ctx.wholeTextFiles("path to image file");
        System.out.println(bigRDD1.partitions().size());
```

In this case, "path to image file" contain more than 200 image files with total size of 91 MB. It shows 2 total of partitions.

I use Spark as local mode (setMaster["local"]) and as I  understand, number of partitions = total file size / hdfs default block size (here is 32MB). So I think the second result is correct as theory.

But in the first case, I dont understand why it has total of 8 partitions even the total file size just 21 MB.?

**UPDATED**

The sequence files in case 1 have created in the different job by:

```
    JavaPairRDD<Text, CustomObj> setsPartitions = clusteSet.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(8));
   setsPartitions.saveAsHadoopFile("path to out put", Text.class, CustomObj.class, MultipleSequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
```

Bacause in my case I known the number of partitions prior so I set it equal 8

Comment: Because in a local mode default parallelism is set to a number of the available cores.

Comment: @zero323 is correct. Just wanted to add that the reason you see 2 partitions for `bigRDD1` is because the wholeTextFiles method uses `WholeTextFileInputFormat` which extends `CombineFileInputFormat` (which in turn combines input splits based on node locality). Since you are running locally, this was likely combined into 1 split; however, the default minimum number of partitions is 2 which is what you are seeing.

Comment: @zero323 I just only set 1 CPU for my instance VM. and if I delete 4 files in case 1 , then the output will be 4. could you explain it ?

Comment: @RohanAletty could you help me also?

Comment: @ndk076 Are your sequence files compressed in a non-splittable format (e.g. gzip)?

Comment: @RohanAletty. no, it haven't. actually I don't use compress option now.

Comment: @ndk076 I did a fair amount of research on this but couldn't find much on how sequence files determine their input splits. However, I also found an [input format](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/CombineSequenceFileInputFormat.html) that could support loading your sequence files into one partition. If you are interested, I could write an answer monkey patching it into the sequence file command.

Comment: @RohanAletty I just updated my question to include the code I used to create multi sequence files. Does it effect to the reading sequence files later? I mean if we stored as 8 separate files then during the reading process Spark will automatically divide them into 8 partitions,?

Comment: @ndk076 I think it might be. This is just speculation (since I couldn't find any hard evidence online) but I believe that `MultipleSequenceFileOutputFormat` is writing each partition to a separate HDFS block since these writes are happening in parallel. Subsequently, since data from each HDFS block is loaded as a separate partition, you will see 8 separate partitions for your loaded RDD.

Comment: @RohanAletty Thanks you a lot for your support.